# Information on Natural Language Processing

Tags: curl, nlp, domparser

I need some explanation about NLP. Could using PHP cURL and DOM Parser to extract data from unstructured html content to form a structured content and then save the content into a database be regarded as a form of NLP ?. Any explanation would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2):

No.  NLP is a term for describing technologies that try to analyze and understand natural language.  In other words, the NLP only applies when you are actually trying to *understand* what is being said.

Answer (score -1):

No — NLP mean Natural Language Processing.The task you said is a pure programming task and has nothing to do with NLP.  XML is a known  format, and you need to write an XML parser can read data from XML and format it into the users required database datatype.

From ha igh level point of view, NLP is about writing a parser that can understand any human language (like English or French) and store the data in a required format, then further using that data for any purpose.

Let us say there is a message “Open Gallery”.  Your NLP parser can parse that statement  and can find that *open* is a verb and that is a noun. This NLP task of NLP is called part-of-speech (POS) tagging.

Any task can be one on a natural language programmatically is called NLP.